# Postman PUT JSON Returns Null

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, request

I have this array that I am trying to use PUT to change the value of `statuses`. I am using Postman (A REST client -- http://www.getpostman.com/). When I change over to the `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab and put the value of `statuses` to `hello` it updates accordingly. Below would be the result.

```
[
{
__v: 0
_id: "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
tagline: "Example tagline"
title: "Example title"
statuses: ["hello"]
}
]
```

But when it gets more complex than a string in the array, I change the tab over to `raw` and try and do a JSON PUT request there by typing `{"statuses":[{"userId": true}]}`.

When doing a GET request, the following is the result.

```
[
{
__v: 0
_id: "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY"
tagline: "Example tagline"
title: "Example title"
statuses:null
}
]
```

How come my JSON PUT request returns `null`? How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your Node.js code to best answer you, but my guess is (I suppose you're using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)) you need to set the `extended` option to `true` so that it's able to parse more complex bodies.

So that would be :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```