# REST Post URLEncoded Key & Value

Tags: json, rest, urlencode, key-value, postman

I have an array `examples`. Trying to submit the key as `examples` and the value as an object in the REST client Postman. Using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab, I enter the key as `examples` and the value as `{"test"}`. I expect to see the result as

```
{ 
"examples" = [{"test"}]
}
```

but instead I see

```
{ 
"examples" = ["{\"test\"}"]
}
```

I assumed this was something to do with the urlencoding, so I tried `key: examples` `value: %7D"test"%7B` (%7B = { and %7D = }), but that wasn't correct either. How do I get the result I'm trying to get?

EDIT: Seems that I'm having the same problem as this post: [Postman PUT JSON Returns Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355158/postman-put-json-returns-null)

Comment: have you tried the form-data tab?

Comment: Yes, it returns null.

Comment: Its hard for me to see the whole picture without any code, I would just be shooting in the dark.

Comment: @meda What type of code would you like to see? You don't think this is the REST client's fault?

Comment: @john how would I know maybe you try to convert data to JSON that was already in json format. but I wouldnt know just be guessing

Comment: @meda What is your guess? Guesses are fine.

Comment: This looks like a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355158/postman-put-json-returns-null

Comment: to me it looks like you are encoding data to json which is already encoded into JSON format

Comment: So how do I do that correctly?

Comment: by fixing your code and make sure you dont re-encode it

Comment: Fixing what in my code? This is also in my code...`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));` does this need to be edited?

Comment: If you don't have any code that does the posting, perhaps a screenshot of your Postman call may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the right answer, but try putting your JSON body in the Raw tab instead.

Comment: Returns null. I can't figure out why! Thanks for guessing though.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I guess I am a little confused though, are you expecting the server to just return whatever you POSTed/PUT?

Comment: Well when I GET it, then yes I expect it to return what I PUT.

Comment: Ok, so you do the PUT then immediately do the GET and that returns null? It's possible there is some issue in the server then and that Postman is actually sending the right body. Is it possible to show the server code that accepts this?

Comment: No the GET does not return null. The `examples` array returns null from the GET.

Comment: Are you putting valid Json in the raw tab? The first example you have should be exactly what you put in the raw field. That might not be much help, sorry I can't help much, I just love Postman though so I hope you get it working for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I put exactly that and it still returns null for `examples`. How frustrating is that!?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to use x-www-form-urlencoded?  If so then the way you pass array values is separated by pipe symbols, for example:

**Key:** param_name

**Value:** redirecturl|no_promotion|change_status_num|no_reuse_session_ind

As other posters mentioned you can try the raw tab.  If you do make sure you JSON validates here: http://jsonlint.com/